# set theory (concept of infinity)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a set. $f$ be a function on $S$ into real line $\mathbb{R}$. 
Let us define $Af$ as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ into power set of $S$, $PS$
$Af(x) = \{s\mid f(s) \leq x\}$

Question: Is $S$ in the range of $Af$?

(as an example we can chose $S=\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = x$)

Thanks
PS: I'm having some technical difficulties in proving few results. It boils down to above. (and related in infinity)

Comment: What do we know about $S$, is it finite or something?

Comment: for finite it is trvial. im unable to understand when S is infinite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S$ is in the range of $Af$ iff $f$ is bounded from above.

If $f$ isn't bounded from above, there is for every $x\in \mathbb{R}$ a $s_x\in S$ with $f(s_x)>x$ and so $s_x\notin Af(x)$ and so $S\neq Af(x)$ which means $S$ isn't in the range.

If $f$ is bounded from above, there is a $x\in \mathbb{R}$ with $f(s)\leq x$ for all $s\in S$ and so $S=Af(x)$  which means $S$ is in the range.

Comment: +1. A concrete example which might help the OP: let $f(x)=x$, and let $S=\mathbb{R}$. Then $Af(x)=\{s: s\le x\}$, and this is never all of $\mathbb{R}$, since $\mathbb{R}$ has no maximal element. By contrast, if we took $S=(0, 1)$, then $Af(1)=S$. So this is what boundedness gets us.

Comment: thanks. i was trying to define probability spaces starting from cdfs and random variables. above puts that in risk as in some cases i will not have sample space in the sigma algebra. so seems i cant go much further.  thanks

Comment: but if i assume /infinity/ belongs to R then I can get over this issue. Because then Af (infinity)  = S and hence S will be in the image of Af. Am I going in right direction plz?